# rollapply with a normalisation function using multiple column data

Tags: r, zoo, rollapply

I have some data that I would like to normalise using a rolling function. My objective is to make the three `var1`, `var2` and `var3` variables time series comparable between themselves.

My current code only scales each variable individually based on its historic `min` and `max` values however I would like to use the `min` and `max` values from the other variables also.

That is, given this very little "mini" sub-sample of the data, my current method would take for `var1` the `min` value as `75.9` and the `max` value as `76.8` and compute the scales (according to the function in the code). For `var2` it would use the `min` value as `13` and the `max` value as `44` and for `var3` it would take the `min` value as `24` and the `max` value as `59`.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  date        var1  var2  var3
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2010-01-01  76.8    13    24
2 2010-01-02  76.4    31    46
3 2010-01-03  75.9    44    59
```

However, different variables have different magnitudes of their size but I want to be able to compare across the variables. So I would like to take the `min` value as `13` and the `max` value as `76.8` and scale all three variables by these numbers. I would like to do this on a rolling basis, updating daily.

Using the code below, I would like to find the `min` and `max` values over a given `90` day period and then compute the normalised result, move forward by 1 day and compute the next `90` day normalised result based on the `min` and `max` of this period.

Code:

```
normaliseFunction <- function(x){
  (x - min(x) / max(x) - min(x))
}

library(dplyr)

normaliseWindowSize = 90

normalisedData <- data %>% 
  mutate(
    var1Normed = zoo::rollapply(
      var1,                # normalise variable 1
      width = normaliseWindowSize,
      by = 1,
      FUN = normaliseFunction,
      align = "left",
      fill = NA
    ),

    var2Normed = zoo::rollapply(
      var2,                # normalise variable 2
      width = normaliseWindowSize,
      by = 1,
      FUN = normaliseFunction,
      align = "left",
      fill = NA
    ),

    var3Normed = zoo::rollapply(
      var3,                # normalise variable 3
      width = normaliseWindowSize,
      by = 1,
      FUN = normaliseFunction,
      align = "left",
      fill = NA
    )
  )
```

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(date = structure(c(14610, 14611, 14612, 14613, 
14614, 14615, 14616, 14617, 14618, 14619, 14620, 14621, 14622, 
14623, 14624, 14625, 14626, 14627, 14628, 14629, 14630, 14631, 
14632, 14633, 14634, 14635, 14636, 14637, 14638, 14639, 14640, 
14641, 14642, 14643, 14644, 14645, 14646, 14647, 14648, 14649, 
14650, 14651, 14652, 14653, 14654, 14655, 14656, 14657, 14658, 
14659, 14660, 14661, 14662, 14663, 14664, 14665, 14666, 14667, 
14668, 14669, 14670, 14671, 14672, 14673, 14674, 14675, 14676, 
14677, 14678, 14679, 14680, 14681, 14682, 14683, 14684, 14685, 
14686, 14687, 14688, 14689, 14690, 14691, 14692, 14693, 14694, 
14695, 14696, 14697, 14698, 14699, 14700, 14701, 14702, 14703, 
14704, 14705, 14706, 14707, 14708, 14709, 14710, 14711, 14712, 
14713, 14714, 14715, 14716, 14717, 14718, 14719, 14720, 14721, 
14722, 14723, 14724, 14725, 14726, 14727, 14728, 14729, 14730, 
14731, 14732, 14733, 14734, 14735, 14736, 14737, 14738, 14739, 
14740, 14741, 14742, 14743, 14744, 14745, 14746, 14747, 14748, 
14749, 14750, 14751, 14752, 14753, 14754, 14755, 14756, 14757, 
14758, 14759, 14760, 14761, 14762, 14763, 14764, 14765, 14766, 
14767, 14768, 14769, 14770, 14771, 14772, 14773, 14774, 14775, 
14776, 14777, 14778, 14779, 14780, 14781, 14782, 14783, 14784, 
14785, 14786, 14787, 14788, 14789, 14790, 14791, 14792, 14793, 
14794, 14795, 14796, 14797, 14798, 14799, 14800, 14801, 14802, 
14803, 14804, 14805, 14806, 14807, 14808, 14809, 14810, 14811, 
14812, 14813, 14814, 14815, 14816, 14817, 14818, 14819, 14820, 
14821, 14822, 14823, 14824, 14825, 14826, 14827, 14828, 14829, 
14830, 14831, 14832, 14833, 14834, 14835, 14836, 14837, 14838, 
14839, 14840, 14841, 14842, 14843, 14844, 14845, 14846, 14847, 
14848, 14849, 14850, 14851, 14852, 14853, 14854, 14855, 14856, 
14857, 14858, 14859, 14860, 14861, 14862, 14863, 14864, 14865, 
14866, 14867, 14868, 14869, 14870, 14871, 14872, 14873, 14874, 
14875, 14876, 14877, 14878, 14879, 14880, 14881, 14882, 14883, 
14884, 14885, 14886, 14887, 14888, 14889, 14890, 14891, 14892, 
14893, 14894, 14895, 14896, 14897, 14898, 14899, 14900, 14901, 
14902, 14903, 14904, 14905, 14906, 14907, 14908, 14909, 14910, 
14911, 14912, 14913, 14914, 14915, 14916, 14917, 14918, 14919, 
14920, 14921, 14922, 14923, 14924, 14925, 14926, 14927, 14928, 
14929, 14930, 14931, 14932, 14933, 14934, 14935, 14936, 14937, 
14938, 14939, 14940, 14941, 14942, 14943, 14944, 14945, 14946, 
14947, 14948, 14949, 14950, 14951, 14952, 14953, 14954, 14955, 
14956, 14957, 14958, 14959, 14960, 14961, 14962, 14963, 14964, 
14965, 14966, 14967, 14968, 14969, 14970, 14971, 14972, 14973, 
14974), class = "Date"), var1 = c(76.7710873995529, 76.3531164480543, 
75.935145496561, 75.5171745450677, 75.0992035935744, 74.6812326420812, 
74.2632616905879, 73.8452907390946, 73.4273197876013, 73.009348836108, 
72.5913778846148, 72.1734069331215, 71.7554359816282, 71.337465030135, 
77, 67, 51, 56, 52, 39, 82, 81, 46, 38, 25, 30, 33, 70, 79, 23, 
22, 43, 78, 93, 75, 31, 28, 65, 53, 33, 55, 28, 46, 25, 39, 50, 
45, 32, 47, 54, 30, 45, 43, 33, 21, 33, 42, 40, 24, 27, 35, 35, 
43, 32, 18, 26, 17, 30, 32.1911583173478, 35.8040286890933, 44, 
37, 24, 67, 68, 59, 75, 62, 42, 40, 54, 58, 41, 32, 21, 23, 38, 
36, 19, 19, 17, 24, 20, 24, 28, 59, 33, 30, 29, 30, 40, 25, 30, 
33, 42, 45, 38, 41, 45, 52, 57, 31, 52, 43, 42, 47, 52, 42, 42, 
41, 21, 18, 18, 15, 23, 33, 38, 20, 17, 24, 38, 27, 26, 26, 15, 
13, 25, 33, 26, 24, 42, 41, 29, 31, 25, 25, 32, 23, 20, 25, 26, 
27, 25, 22, 29, 33, 24, 28, 24, 33, 19, 20, 24, 12, 23, 17, 35, 
42, 40, 16, 9, 29, 39, 42, 39, 38, 21, 20, 26, 28, 37, 43, 54, 
22, 22, 25, 36, 45, 49, 36, 26, 35, 39, 37, 24, 29.4381452808882, 
29.5843833126788, 29.7306213444694, 29.87685937626, 30.0230974080506, 
30.1693354398412, 30.3155734716318, 30.4618115034224, 30.608049535213, 
30.7542875670036, 30.9005255987942, 31.0467636305848, 31.1930016623754, 
31.339239694166, 31.4854777259566, 31.6317157577472, 31.7779537895378, 
31.9241918213284, 32.070429853119, 32.2166678849096, 32.3629059167003, 
32.5091439484909, 32.6553819802815, 32.8016200120721, 32.9478580438627, 
33.0940960756533, 33.2403341074439, 33.3865721392345, 33.5328101710251, 
33.6790482028157, 33.8252862346063, 33.9715242663969, 34.1177622981875, 
33, 38, 34, 37, 32, 22, 29, 28, 47, 56, 28, 15, 13, 30, 39, 32, 
44, 44, 49, 49, 56, 19, 21, 37, 47, 48, 36, 37, 64, 61, 50, 35, 
24, 30, 55, 63, 60, 54, 22, 13, 21, 43, 53, 47, 61, 64, 57, 28, 
27, 54, 68, 53, 54, 37, 26, 55, 24, 50, 55, 55, 32, 15, 45, 78, 
87, 76, 88, 74, 47, 21, 73, 92, 108, 76, 24, 16, 15, 48, 83, 
61, 73, 64, 39, 23, 15, 36, 42, 72, 57, 47, 30, 65, 36, 46, 68, 
29, 23, 47, 84, 67, 59, 45, 41, 50, 56, 58, 36, 43, 50, 64, 53, 
36, 45, 34, 53, 63, 50, 55, 89, 52, 28, 65, 95, 81, 28, 57, 63, 
60, 38, 39, 41, 65, 90, 90, 76, 67, 57), var2 = c(13, 31, 44, 
50, 36, 22, 30, 22, 21, 37, 57, 55, 54, 19, 53, 46, 33, 44, 44, 
27, 60, 71, 44, 30, 25, 29, 30, 58, 49, 19, 18, 35, 46, 62, 56, 
23, 25, 47, 40, 27, 33, 25, 37, 22, 24, 50, 55, 31, 43, 41, 23, 
41, 35, 33, 23, 31, 30, 35, 13, 21, 35, 32, 30, 38, 31, 27, 21, 
34, 35, 35, 33, 34, 23, 59, 46, 35, 52, 44, 25, 23, 33, 37, 21, 
23, 18, 14, 28, 30, 16, 13, 9, 14, 16, 17, 22, 31, 21, 23, 20, 
17, 19, 23, 28, 34, 33, 33, 27, 18, 28, 35, 40, 23, 32, 30, 29, 
32, 39, 22, 22, 28, 13, 13, 12, 11, 17, 27, 27, 16, 12, 14, 24, 
14, 19, 19, 10, 12, 23, 33, 20, 20, 31, 26, 16, 19, 12, 18, 30, 
28, 25, 33, 35, 32, 36, 25, 33, 33, 24, 23, 24, 28, 21, 21, 30, 
20, 35, 21, 34, 39, 46, 21, 14, 29, 39, 47, 34, 36, 24, 26, 30, 
25, 25, 25, 25, 24, 23, 22, 22, 23, 22, 22, 28, 35, 37, 32, 24, 
34, 53, 24, 21, 47, 32, 25, 24, 21, 19, 15, 22, 33, 52, 32, 29, 
30, 27, 28, 19, 25, 21, 28, 27, 38, 36, 42, 34, 36, 15, 15, 15, 
17, 27, 36, 37, 37, 44, 23, 27, 26, 47, 54, 28, 20, 20, 37, 36, 
30, 46, 36, 43, 47, 54, 18, 20, 35, 45, 50, 47, 38, 55, 55, 43, 
40, 26, 29, 38, 30, 52, 51, 25, 20, 24, 44, 49, 42, 58, 67, 61, 
32, 24, 49, 67, 44, 43, 34, 27, 46, 24, 42, 53, 53, 38, 22, 44, 
77, 79, 69, 81, 65, 57, 29, 64, 75, 94, 60, 27, 20, 21, 45, 78, 
59, 56, 57, 33, 27, 18, 34, 45, 62, 52, 44, 31, 51, 41, 45, 59, 
32, 26, 38, 56, 60, 59, 48, 49, 52, 62, 53, 37, 39, 43, 60, 61, 
33, 51, 35, 52, 51, 44, 52, 75, 51, 35, 53, 85, 69, 38, 50, 63, 
54, 40, 35, 47, 57, 74, 75, 69, 60, 50), var3 = c(24, 46, 59, 
63, 54, 35, 43, 39, 40, 47, 68, 69, 68, 38, 74, 66, 56, 62, 57, 
44, 80, 93, 68, 52, 44, 45, 52, 80, 76, 46, 39, 62, 74, 93, 75, 
36, 48, 66, 54, 52, 54, 54, 63, 44, 53, 64, 68, 38, 62, 61, 40, 
54, 45, 43, 29, 44, 46, 51, 31, 32, 53, 44, 46, 54, 51, 42, 43, 
56, 64, 63, 57, 57, 48, 86, 72, 66, 83, 65, 48, 44, 48, 56, 33, 
32, 28, 33, 52, 41, 26, 30, 33, 30, 32, 38, 48, 56, 49, 50, 50, 
48, 52, 43, 47, 48, 53, 48, 43, 33, 42, 59, 68, 33, 55, 49, 47, 
51, 68, 48, 40, 51, 29, 34, 29, 31, 39, 44, 48, 28, 25, 25, 40, 
25, 34, 39, 24, 29, 49, 59, 49, 50, 65, 55, 40, 39, 24, 30, 42, 
38, 39, 41, 44, 45, 45, 41, 55, 51, 31, 31, 25, 28, 21, 23, 36, 
33, 44, 33, 46, 56, 62, 40, 33, 39, 52, 61, 54, 56, 46, 47, 49, 
49, 61, 61, 77, 37, 54, 56, 48, 62, 76, 48, 50, 46, 44, 39, 30, 
47, 63, 50, 34, 59, 43, 33, 29, 38, 34, 30, 40, 49, 71, 57, 53, 
52, 39, 41, 38, 41, 38, 49, 46, 54, 45, 59, 60, 53, 31, 28, 29, 
27, 35, 40, 47, 55, 59, 39, 29, 29, 60, 64, 45, 45, 35, 56, 48, 
42, 55, 50, 65, 64, 63, 20, 34, 49, 64, 65, 67, 54, 74, 74, 48, 
51, 43, 40, 56, 56, 62, 60, 42, 39, 36, 52, 66, 53, 67, 73, 75, 
39, 33, 58, 77, 56, 54, 44, 29, 58, 40, 55, 66, 67, 58, 35, 57, 
84, 94, 87, 92, 81, 65, 44, 70, 94, 111, 66, 33, 31, 37, 59, 
85, 78, 71, 64, 44, 29, 23, 44, 50, 74, 64, 50, 44, 58, 45, 54, 
66, 40, 31, 48, 66, 75, 71, 64, 67, 65, 68, 58, 38, 50, 55, 73, 
73, 54, 57, 45, 66, 66, 64, 74, 97, 68, 54, 68, 94, 79, 45, 55, 
70, 62, 51, 50, 52, 69, 88, 95, 92, 75, 59)), row.names = c(NA, 
-365L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to take the minimum over the next 90 days including the current day for all three variables at once and get a single minimum value which is applied to the first row of the 90 day period.  Similarly for maximum. To do that specify `by.column = FALSE` and use the indicated `normalise` function. We convert it to zoo first, perform the rolling calculation and convert the result back to a data frame at the end but depending on what you are doing it might be more convenient to just leave it as a zoo object in which case the last line can be omitted.  (If you want to perform the normalization for each column separately remove `by.column=FALSE` and change `x[1, ]` to `x[1]` in `normalise`.)

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

normalise <- function(x) (x[1, ] - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))
w <- 90

data %>% 
  read.zoo %>%
  rollapply(w, normalise, fill = NA, by.column = FALSE, align = "left") %>%
  fortify.zoo
```

### Update

Have revised the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Just so I understand clearly what is going on. The current code takes the minimum of the vars and also the maximum of the vars over the 90 day period and then computes the `normalise` function? I am a little confused by the output since we have an NA value starting from 2010-12-31 but we should have the NA value starting from 2010-01-01.

Comment: Setting `align = "right"` seems to solve the issue but is this taking the first 90 days (begining in 2010-01-01 until 2010-03-30) and then computing the min / max of this period to make the normalised computation on the 2010-03-31?

Comment: Yes, with align = "right" it takes the 90 days up to and including the current day. If you use align = "right" then you would want `x[nrow(x), ]` instead of `x[1, ]` because the current row would then be the last row rather than the first.  Try `rollapplyr(1:10, 3, toString, fill = NA)` to understand what it is passing to the function.  Note the r at the end of rollapply which means align = "right".